# SQL Server 2008 t-SQL - Insert multiple record IDs into varchar column as CSV

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

I have 2 tables in SQL Server 2008 database - tblQuestion and tblSummary. I'm selecting QuestionIDs from tblQuestion as follows.

```
SELECT QuestionId from tblQuestion WHERE Status='Completed';
```

The result is as follows (from multiple records),

```
QuestionId 
----------
1
2
5
7
8
9

[6 rows]
```

Now, I need to insert above selected IDs to "CompletedSections" column (which is VARCHAR type) in tblSummary. It should be inserted as a CSV like format - 1,2,5,7,8,9

For example, if I select those from tblSummary will be as follows.

```
SELECT CompletedSections FROM tblSummary WHERE <Some Condition>
```

Result should be,

```
CompletedSections 
-----------------
1,2,5,7,8,9

[1 row]
```

How this can be done at the database level using t-SQL (not using any programming language like C#)? I'm hoping to implement this with t-SQL using a scheduled SQL SP/ Function/ Trigger.

Thanks,

Chatur

Comment: Why, oh why, do you want to store these as CSV? This is like throwing all your bowls, forks and glasses in a single drawer.

Comment: see the following link so something similar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/) is a solution I have used in the past. It is a little hacky, but it should be faster than using a cursor to create the CSV. Here is some example code to get you started.

```
DECLARE @tblQuestion TABLE
(
     QuestionId nvarchar(10)
)

DECLARE @tblSummary TABLE
(
    CompletedSections nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @tblQuestion
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)

INSERT INTO @tblSummary
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ',' + QuestionId 
from @tblQuestion 
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CSV

SELECT * FROM @tblSummary
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job;

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(5000)

SELECT @S=ISNULL(@S+ ',', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),QuestionId)
FROM tblQuestion 

SELECT @S
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE A_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT QuestionId from tblQuestion WHERE Status='Completed'

    OPEN A_CURSOR
    FETCH A_CURSOR INTO @VALUE

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    if @STRING <> ''
    set @STRING = @STRING + ', '

    set @STRING = @STRING + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@VALUE)

    FETCH A_CURSOR INTO @VALUE

    END

    CLOSE A_CURSOR

    DEALLOCATE A_CURSOR

    INSERT INTO CompletedSection (tblSummary) SELECT @STRING
```

Comment: Don't use a cursor for this, it can be solved ina set-based manner.

Comment: ok, good to learn somethign new, thanks for the minuses